# Can we use 3.3V voltage divider circuit from 5V voltage regulator for (800ma load and 3.3v)?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

I am using (lm2576) 5.0v regulator from 12v battery 2-amps for my raspberry pi. I want to use 3 LDR and 5 proximity IR sensor for my mini project. For all sensor I need only 3.3V voltage. It is sufficient to use 3.3V voltage divider circuit from lm2576-5.0 v reg or else I have to use 3.3 voltage regulator so that I can convert 5v(lm2576) to 3.3v(lm1117/lm3940)

I got 3.3v reg-lm3940 I connected through lm2576 but both regulator getting heat too much and inductor got fire

Comment: Have you tried using LM7805(5v regulator) & LD33V(3.3v regulator)?

Comment: No you can't use a divider. Don't use linear regulators for 800ma. Get a couple of small switchmode boards and use those.

Comment: Are you using any heatsinks?

Comment: No,i m not using lm7805 i need 2 amps as output load for that i m using lm2576.

Comment: yes i m using heatsink

Comment: i should prefer ld33

Comment: So what's your heatsink[s] K/W rating[s] and what temperature is "heat too much"? (If you don't have an accurate way to measure: does it hurt when you put your finger on the sink? does it sizzle if you put your wet finger on it?) Regarding your inductor: the only way it could have caught fire is if you chose the an inappropriate current rating for it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are wasting a lot of energy converting from 12V down to 3.3V, and this is the reason for the overheating. A well designed circuit would waste very little power. Have you looked into using an integrated 12V to 3.3V dc-dc converter ?

Comment: ho if it is that reason then can i use ld33/tl2575-33

Comment: You can use these devices but they also require considerable external components. The benefit of the DC-DC converter is that it is all one device (nothing to get wrong, if you are not an electronics specialist)

Answer (score 0):

Use a buck converter, it does not waste so much energy (at least 90% efficiency) like a linear device will do. For example: [TL2575-33 (1-A Simple Step-Down Switching Voltage Regulators)](http://www.ti.com/product/tl2575-33)